# Apply button javascript to an a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My friend gave me this code that will allow a *smooth scroll effect* to the page once the user pushes an anchor button:

```
<form id = "button_design" action="#page2">
     <input type="submit" class="anchor-button" value="Page 2" />
</form>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(function() {
$('input.anchor-button').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var hash = $(this).parent('form').attr('action');
var target = $(hash);
target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + hash.slice(1) +']');
if (target.length) {
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: target.offset().top
 }, 1000);
}

});
});
```

It works for `input type = "submit"` only and I want to try to use this code to my `<a href ="#page3"...` which is only a link and not a button. Can anyone help me to convert the code to make it apply to `a href` too? I tried messing around with it but I get nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have to learn about selectors to work with JS. Here is an example with link. Every link must has class `anchor` and target in it's `href` attribute. So you don't need a form to wrap it:

```
<a class="anchor" href="#page2"> Page 2 </a>
```

And script for this markup

```
$(function () {
    $('a.anchor').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var hash = $(this).attr('href');
        var target = $(hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + hash.slice(1) + ']');

        if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change the tag to `a` (both in jQuery and HTML) the code functions basically the same. Example:

```js
$(function() {
$('a.anchor-button').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var hash = $(this).parent('form').attr('action');
var target = $(hash);
target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + hash.slice(1) +']');
if (target.length) {
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: target.offset().top
 }, 1000);
}

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id = "button_design" action="#page2">
     <a class="anchor-button" href="javascript:void(0)"> Page 2 </a>
</form>

<div style="height:800px; background-color:blue;">&nbsp;</div>
<div name="page2">test</div>
```